# Save and retrieve list of selected items in a listview in QML

Tags: listview, qml

I'm using Qt for Symbian. In my mainwindow.cpp I have a QPushButton and a QListWidget. Pressing the button will display a Qml page, which has a listview with checkboxes in each row. I can check or uncheck the items. When I press the Back toolbutton, the selected items are listed in the QListWidget of the mainwindow.

When I reopen the Qml page (i.e., Press the QPushButton again), I need to retrieve the listview with selected items also. How to achieve that.? Is there anything like saveState() or restoreState() in qml? If not, is there any other possible methods to achieve this?

Edited:

Here is my code:

**contacts.qml**

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.top: statusBar.bottom
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: toolBar.top
    clip: true
    model: stdModel
    //delegate: contactListDelegate
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::createList()
{
QContactManager *contactManager = new QContactManager("symbian");    
QList<QContactLocalId> contactIds = contactManager->contactIds();
QContact currContact;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
QImage m_thumbnail;

foreach (const QContactLocalId& id, contactIds)
{
currContact = contactManager->contact(id);
if(currContact.type() == QContactType::TypeContact)
{
    QContactThumbnail avatar(currContact.detail(QContactThumbnail::DefinitionName));
    m_thumbnail = avatar.thumbnail();

    QStandardItem *items = new QStandardItem();
    //items->setData(currContact.displayLabel(), Qt::DisplayRole);
    //items->setData(QPixmap::fromImage(m_thumbnail), Qt::DecorationRole);
    items->setText(currContact.displayLabel());

    if(m_thumbnail.isNull())
    {
        items->setIcon(contactIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        items->setIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(m_thumbnail));
    }
    model->appendRow(items);
}
}
}

void MainWindow::viewQml()
{
    QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView;
    qmlView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/contacts.qml"));
    qmlView->rootContext()->setContextProperty("stdModel", model);
    qmlView->show();
}
```

Comment: Try putting setcontextproperty before set source this should solve the  reference not found problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use QML ContactModel as your model then you should create a separate C++ model and save the state in this model.

The example with c++ class:

```
class CheckedModel : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  CheckedModel(QObject *parent);
  Q_INVOKABLE void setSize(int count) {vector.resize(count)};
  Q_INVOKABLE bool isChecked(int index) {return vector[index]};
  Q_INVOKABLE void check(int index, bool checked) {vector[index] = checked};
private:
  std::vector<bool> vector;
};
```

You than need to instantiate it and give to the QML.

```
CheckedModel myModel;
QDeclarativeView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theCheckedModel", &myModel);
view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("yourqmlfile.qml"));
view.show();
```

And then the last thing is using it from QML:

```
ListView {
  id: listView
  model: contactModel
  delegate: contactListDelegate
  onCountChanged: {
    theCheckedModel.setSize(count);
  }
}
```

And in the MouseArea on your delegate do this:

```
onClicked: {
  if(selectbox.checked == false)
  {
    selectbox.checked = true
    theCheckedModel.check(index, true);
  }
  else if(selectbox.checked == true)
  {
    selectbox.checked = false
    theCheckedModel.check(index, true);
  }
}
```

Last thing is to load this to the checkbox:

```
CheckBox {
  id: selectbox
  Component.onComplete{
    selectbox.checked = theCheckedModel.isChecked(index);
  }
}
```

Note that his is just the main things you need to do and might not compile straight away. Let me know if you still have problems. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. But I don't understand. What do u mean by "Saving state as part of the model" ? Can u pls show a piece of code if possible...?

Comment: What model are you using QML or C++? Add a new role/attribute to your model and when the Checkbox is clicked change the value of that attribute.

Comment: Actually I'm using 'contact model' as the model for listview. Also I have a custom delegate as Component. And of course, I'm displaying a list of contacts.

Comment: Is it [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qml-contactmodel.html) QML model? If it is than maybe you could use 'modified' field to store if it has been checked (not sure if that will work). Another more difficult solution is to try to write your own model.

Comment: The component has a listitem. The listitem has a image(contact avatar), a listitemtext(name of the contact) and a checkbox. The Mousearea fills the listitem. Onclicking the listitem, user can check or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: I understand what you display. The thing that I am asking is what is the model that you use for your ListView (i.e. the value that you set to the ListView 'model' parameter). Is it a c++ class derived from QAbstractListModel or a qml model i.e. ListModel in QML file. In either case you can add bool parameter to that model and change it from QML e.g. onClick { model.set(...)}

Comment: I got it. Yes. It is the Qml Contactmodel. It is not derived from C++. But how and where to add bool parameter to the model? Some coding will be helpful.

Comment: In that case its going to be more difficult. You can't change the ContactModel so the easiest way then is to create a c++ class that stores a vector of bools and call its method each time the item is checked/unchecked in QML. You can read here more on c++ to QML interaction: [link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtbinding.html)

Comment: 'create a c++ class that stores a vector of bools' - Can you please explain this. I read the link but find no clue.

Comment: I tried your solution. But instead of using Qml ContactModel, now I'm trying to use QAbstractListModel (from C++). But I didn't tried this before. Where and how to start? Are there any example links.?

Comment: So far, I tried this. (Pasted my code). Is that alright? But I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: stdModel"